# Model not registered while populating data from mongodb in nextjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js13

I have 3 models USER , CATEGORY , PRODUCT . product model has two fields that refer to other two models . so when i try to populate data it throws an error saying

users isn't registered and same for category

Like if i directly hit the get_all_product endpoint without logging in or collecting category ( mean both user and category model not awaked) it throws error for category and if the category endpoint are hitted then it show me users isn't registered

A way to fix that i found is if i collect data from users collection like user profile and then i collected data from category model like collect all category  and hit get all product endpoint it give me all data as expected

But if i try to get it without hitting user or category endpoint its throws an error as i am populating user and category

This is not a good approach as i am building a n ecommerce app where an guest user can explore categories and product so this create a problem for me and always throws an error of users model not registered so what the best fix for this issue here is my models

**Category model**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import User from "./User";

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Name"],
        unique: true,
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Slug"],
        unique: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Description"],
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'inactive',
        enum: ['active', 'inactive']
    },
    isFeatured: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    addedBy : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
    },
}, {timestamps: true});

const Category =  mongoose.models.categories || mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);
export default Category;
```

**product model**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categories',
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Name"], 
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Slug"],
    },
    images: {
        type: [String],
        default: [],
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Price"],
    },
    salePrice: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Quantity"],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Description"],
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'inactive',
        enum: ['active', 'inactive' , 'rejected']
    },
    isFeatured: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    addedBy : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
    },
}, {timestamps: true});


const Product =  mongoose.models.products || mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
export default Product;
```

**usermodel**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Name"],
        trim: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Email"],
        trim: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please Provide an Password"],
        trim: true,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        trim : true,
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        trim : true,
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        trim : true,
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        trim : true,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        trim : true,
    }, 
    postalCode: {
        type: String,
        trim : true,
    },
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    image : {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    role : {
        type: String,
        default: 'customer',
        enum : ['admin' , 'vendor' , 'customer']
    },
    isVendorApproved : {
        type: String,
        default: 'pending',
        enum : ['pending' , 'approved' , 'rejected']
    },
    isBlackList : {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    pinCode: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    },
    resetCode: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
    }

},{timestamps : true})

const User = mongoose.models.users || mongoose.model('users' , userSchema);
export default User;
```

**db connection**

```
import mongoose, { ConnectOptions } from 'mongoose';


interface connectedOptions extends ConnectOptions{
    useNewUrlParser: boolean,
    useUnifiedTopology: boolean,
}

const options: connectedOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

const connectDB = async () => {
    const connectionUrl: string = process.env.DB_URI as string;
    mongoose.connect(connectionUrl , options )
        .then(() => console.log(`Database connected successfully`))
        .catch((err) => console.log("Getting Error from DB connection" + err.message))
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
};

export default connectDB;
```

**product endpoint example**

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectDB from "@/db";
import Product from "@/models/Product";

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    connectDB();
    try {
        const product = await Product.find({}).populate('category').populate('addedBy' )
        return NextResponse.json({ data: product, success: true, msg: "Products Collected successfully" });
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(" ~ file: route.ts:9 ~ GET ~ error:", error.message)
        return NextResponse.json({ success: false, msg: "something went wrong !" });
    }
}
```

**Note**

In mern stack where the mongodb is connected always as app starts, I never face such issues so maybe a consistent connection maybe a good fix

In nextjs db connected only when we hit some endpoint as you can see the route example of products calling connectDB()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**

> this is just a quick fix but not a permanent solution I am still finding the answer

One of Quick fix i findout is doing a dummy query to register the Model.This is optimal solution I figured out rather sending 3 request from client side

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectDB from "@/db";
import Product from "@/models/Product";
import User from "@/models/User";
import Category from "@/models/Category";

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    connectDB();
    try {
        const getAnyUser =  await User.findOne({});
        const getAnyCategory =  await Category.findOne({});
        const product = await Product.find({}).populate('category').populate('addedBy' )
        return NextResponse.json({ data: product, success: true, msg: "Products Collected successfully" });
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(" ~ file: route.ts:9 ~ GET ~ error:", error.message)
        return NextResponse.json({ success: false, msg: "something went wrong !" });
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me out so much. Thanks @Abdullah.